# Meaning of auto& :

Tags: c++, syntax

I understand that auto means type deduction.  I've never seen it used as `auto&` and furthermore I don't understand what `:` is doing in this short code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

void PrintMe() {
    std::cout << "Hello from thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(PrintMe));
    }

    for(auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can guess this is some sort of syntatic sugar that replaces

```
for(std::vector<std::thread>::iterator it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); it++ ) {
    (*it).join();
}
```

but I don't understand how this syntax works and what that & sign is doing there.

Comment: It's a range-based for and a reference.

Comment: Aww, that `(*)` operator! Should've been written as `it->join();`...

Comment: @H2CO3 would have but I was trying to make it more like the original loop with .join() ;)  Hehehe.

Comment: look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: prefer `++it` over `it++`

Comment: Seems like a moot point.  Why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are almost correct with your sample code.

Auto meaning was redefined in C++11. The compiler will inferer the right type of the variable that is being used.

The syntax with `:` it's a range based for. It means that loop will parse each element inside threads vector.

Inside the for, you need to specify the alias `auto&` in order to avoid creating a copy of the elements inside the vector within the `thread` variable. In this way every operation done on the `thread` var is done on the element inside the `threads` vector. Moreover, in a range-based for, you always want to use a reference `&` for performance reasons.

Comment: `auto` was not introduced in C++11. It only had its meaning re-defined.

Comment: Okay!! Thank you for your answer!  I'd accept it already but it says I have to wait.  I compiled without & (and of course it failed because of thread) but I see what the difference is now.