# Why am I Getting incorrect answer for large inputs

Tags: c++

You are given a square n×n map. Each cell of the map has a value in it denoting the depth of the appropriate area. We will call a cell of the map a cavity if and only if this cell is not on the border of the map and each cell adjacent to it has strictly smaller depth. Two cells are adjacent if they have a common side.

You need to find all the cavities on the map and depict them with character X.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer n (1≤n≤100), denoting the size of the map. Each of the following n lines contains n positive digits without spaces. A digit (1-9) denotes the depth of the appropriate area.

Output Format

Output n lines, denoting the resulting map. Each cavity should be replaced with character X.

Sample Input

```
 4
 1112   
 1912 
 1892
 1234
```

Sample Output

```
 1112
 1X12
 18X2
 1234
```

Now, I made this code. But this shows incorrect answer for large values, that is the value of n being 99 or 100 or 96.

This basically takes the input number and divides each row of the input array into individual digits. Then it compares each digit with the next and previous digit to check if it is greater than or less than the considered digit. However, it shows wrong answer for large values of `n`.

Here is the working code. ( Works fine on sample input )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int n, i = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int values[1000];
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int p;
        cin >> p;
        values[i] = p;
    }
    char digits[1000][1000];
    int foo;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        foo = n - 1;
        while (values[i] != 0) {
            digits[i][foo] = values[i] % 10 + 48;
            values[i] = values[i] / 10;
            foo--;
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        j = 1;
        while (j != n - 1) {
            if (digits[i][j] > digits[i][j - 1] &&
                digits[i][j] > digits[i][j + 1]) {
                digits[i][j] = 'X';
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%c", digits[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This shows incorrect answer for large values of the input such as the value of `n` being `96` or `100`. I don't understand why? Is there any way I can optimize it?

[Test Input File Link](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/3305/input05.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINGOTNJCTGAUP7NA&Expires=1407350615&Signature=eWhBkFUiVk3oxtvJ0BiWaUDfocw%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Not working for the above input.

PS: This is not a homework question. I am not able to guess how to solve it.

Comment: What is an "incorrect output" ? Do you know you have implicit casts from `int` to `char` ?

Comment: @quantdev, incorrect output means my code doesn't pass the testcases mentioned. I know that, but since I am printing a character array, I added the ASCII Value.

Comment: Unrelated: From one adrenaline junky to another, a near-megabyte local array? Feeling a little daring? And if that really is your input file format, you seriously need to check your input validations.

Comment: @WhozCraig, the size doesn't really matter too much here.

Comment: @user3845968 Um.. ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking two adjacent cells. Each cell has four adjacent cells: left, right, up down. You need to also check the top and bottom cells like this:

```
if ( digits[i][j] > digits[i][j-1] && digits[i][j] > digits[i][j+1] && digits[i][j] > digits[i-1][j] && digits[i][j] > digits[i+1][j] )
{
    digits[i][j] = 'X';
}
```

Comment: by including this condition, it passed more testcases but it still shows wrong answer on the input that I attached link of. Do you see any other error in this?

Answer (score 0):

Some problems in the code:

- In the input content provided in the question the number are in a range represented by a `int` type variable, but the content of the numbers in the file reference by the link provided the numbers are way out of range of any integer type in C++. You need to be able to storage up to 100 digits. This is the primary cause of your problem, it's the digits of each row. You could treat then as `std::string` to solved.
- According to the description of the problem a check is needed to cell adjacent upper and down.

Some improvement:

- Using `std::vector` instead of `C array`. Don't need to waste unused memory (by the way in the statement of the problem they say the number of rows would be between 1 and 100, you could declared `values` and `digits` variables to that lenght), the vector manage their memory automatically (grow when needed), they have checking of out of bound indexing, etc...
- Using `std::string` instead of `int`, (read previous why).
- Using `std::getline` to read the file line by line.
- The values of the `std::string` could be compared as char because they are digits, and '0' = 0x30 .. '9' = 0x39 and the same order of the digit apply to their char representation.

Code (Tested GCC 4.9.0 with C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned int lines;
    std::cin >> lines;

    std::vector<std::string> values;
    values.reserve(lines);

    // Reading the matrix
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line); // Reading the rest of the first line
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        values.push_back(line);
    }

    // Checking the depths and marking the cavities
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {
        const auto& actual_number = values[i];
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j < actual_number.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (actual_number[j] > actual_number[j - 1] &&
                actual_number[j] > actual_number[j + 1] &&
                actual_number[j] > values[i - 1][j] &&
                actual_number[j] > values[i + 1][j]) {
                values[i][j] = 'X';
            }
        }
    }

    // Printing output
    for (const auto& n : values) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the big sample input file, the output is the same numbers because they are all 9, there is no one bigger.

A version using as base the provided code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    int n, i = 0;
    cin >> n;
    char values[100][100]; // changed the limit
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> values[i]; // reading the line. 'int p;' not necessary
    }

    // declaration of digits, and initialization not necessary

    for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        j = 1;
        while (j != n - 1) {
            if (values[i][j] > values[i][j - 1] &&
                values[i][j] > values[i][j + 1] &&
                values[i][j] > values[i - 1][j] &&
                values[i][j] > values[i + 1][j]) {
                values[i][j] = 'X';
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%c", values[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am new to C++, as you might have guessed since my code was almost similar to C. I wanted to ask one thing. Can we parse the string like a simple array as you have done? Like, `actual_number[j]` ?

Comment: Yes, calling the index operator of the `std::string` would give you the character in that position of the string.

Comment: And just one more thing, why have you used `const auto& actual_number = values[i];`. What is the meaning of `const auto&` here? I understood in the loop while printing why you have used `const auto&` from this post: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414299/meaning-of-auto`.

Comment: `auto` is a new addition to the C++11 standard, it mean that the compiler would deduce the type of the variable taking into account the assigned value. In this case it mean `const std::string&`, `actual_number` would hold a non-modificable `std::string` by references (by references is important to avoid unnecessary copies).

Comment: `values.reserve()`, why have you used it? Isn't it a bit unncessary here? ( Also, because when I read it, I wasn't able to understand it on SO only ).

Comment: it's for reserve the memory that would use the vector. If the numbers of elements is known, it could provide performance gain, because the vector would not need to grow while inserting the elements (until that size at least).

Comment: thanks a lot for the extended help. I am really grateful to you. Just had one last doubt, I sort of now understand the full code that you posted earlier ( the above one, that is ). I want to know why you have done `int main (int argc, char * argv)`. I know this is for command line arguments, but that is not needed here. Also, when I run the code you posted earlier, it prints an extra newline. Where is that happening, I cannot see it. That is actually creating somewhat a trouble.

Comment: The thing is I learnt a lot from the code you posted earlier, that is why, I am looking at it so closely and asking these doubts. Thanks again. :)

Comment: `int main()` is OK and is [standard conformant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main), `int main(void)` is for compatibility with `C` and has some [unexpected result in C++](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284376&answer=1044841143), in this case the memory muscle take in, and i write what i almost always write. Should have be `int main()` because the parameters are no used.

Comment: @user3845968 Re the use of `auto` above, it is pure obfuscation.  It's just as easy, and much clearer, to write `std::string const&`.  (Which is a shame, because the rest of the code is very nicely written.)  Or even just `std::string`; the extra copies won't make any difference here (but most C++ programmers do automatically use a reference to const in such cases).

Comment: @NetVipeC, why the code you posted earlier prints an extra new line? For example, with the test case mentioned, it gives the output as ` 1112 1X12 18X2 1234`. ( i.e. these numbers themselves are in newlines, but, there is an empty line in the beginning before `1112`. Why is that happening?

Comment: @JamesKanze the `extra copy` wont make any difference here and the `reserve` either, but it's good practice to present the beginner with code that is correct, but also is performance, a lot of real world code wont be that easy the matter to solve and the volume of input data. With respect to `auto` there is a lot of critics in favor and again their generalized use even between C++ gurus (Herb Sutter, Scott Meyers, etc...). I don't think that it's obfuscation, but in this specific case, really don't mind either, I don't see this case as something really important to me to make a stand.

Comment: @user3845968 the new line problem is because `std::cin >> lines;` read an int but not the entire line, because of that the first line read by the loop is the rest of the first line (only its left the new line marker, empty line). Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to define two arrays one of which has elements' type int.

Here is a simple solution that satisfies conditions of your assignment
The program reads input line by line. At first it reads the first line with the number of the size of the map and converts it to an object of type size_t.
Then it initializes the map of size n * n with characters '0' by default.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    std::memset( map[i], '0', n );
}
```

Adter that it reads each line with digits and copy it in the corresponding row of the map using standard C function `std::memcpy`

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n && std::getline( std::cin, line ); i++ )
{
    line = line.substr( 0, n );
    std::memcpy( map[i], line.c_str(), line.size() );
}
```

As the input can be erroneous and a line can contain more or less than n characters we extract from the read line exactly n characters and copy them in the row.

In fact after that the assignment is done. All you need is to compare each element inside the map that it greater than adjusted elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char map[N][N];

    std::string line;
    std::getline( std::cin, line );

    size_t n = std::stoul( line );
    if ( N < n ) n = N;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::memset( map[i], '0', n );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n && std::getline( std::cin, line ); i++ )
    {
        line = line.substr( 0, n );
        std::memcpy( map[i], line.c_str(), line.size() );
    }

    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) std::cout << map[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i + 1 < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 1; j + 1 < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( map[i][j-1] < map[i][j] &&
                 map[i][j+1] < map[i][j] &&
                 map[i-1][j] < map[i][j] &&
                 map[i+1][j] < map[i][j] )
            {
                map[i][j] = 'X';
            }
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) std::cout << map[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
4
1 1 1 2 
1 9 1 2 
1 8 9 2 
1 2 3 4 

1 1 1 2 
1 X 1 2 
1 8 X 2 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: way too difficult to understand for me considering the fact that I am beginner. Please add some explanation to it. Thanks. :)
PS: I know I am asking too much. But thanks again. :)